# Other css box is moving when im writing to the one im using

Tags: html, css

So when im trying to add a paragraph to my box, the other one moves.. Ive been looking to see if its something wrong with the margin or so, but not that i can see.
I have absolutely no idea how to fix it.
This is how it looks before i do something:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5SFj.jpg
This is how it looks after i add some text or whatever to the box
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Zyx.jpg

As you can see, the other box is moving, and the more i write, the further down its going.
Would appreciate some explanation here.

HTML CODE:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Inlamningsuppgift 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1> Inlamningsuppgift 1 </h1>
    </header>
    <nav id="firstnav">
        <a href="start.html" id="start"> Start </a>
        <a href="filmer.html" id="filmer"> Filmer </a>
        <a href="bildspel.html" id="bildspel"> Bildspel </a>
        <select>
          <option value="Blue"> Blå </option>
          <option value="Red"> Röd </option>
          <option value="Violet"> Lila </option>
        </select>
    </nav>
  <section>
    <h3> Välkommen till min webbplats! </h3>

    <article id="presentation">
      <h4> Vem är skaparen av sidan? </h4>
    </article>

    <article id="anledning">
      <h4> Anledning till att jag gör denna sidan </h4>
      <p> hej
    </article>

    <article id="utmaningar">
      <h4> Tre saker jag tyckt varit utmanande med uppgiften </h4>
      <ul>
        <li> Sak 1 </li>
        <li> Sak 2 </li>
        <li> Sak 3 </li>
      </ul>
    </article>
  </section>
  <footer>

  </footer>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS CODE:

```
    #wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:970px;
}
header{
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
#firstnav{
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;

}
#start{
  margin-right: 250px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#filmer{
  margin-right: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#bildspel{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
nav select{
  float: right;
  width:250px;
}
section{
  background-color: grey;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
section h3{
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
}
#presentation{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 75px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  clear: both;
}
#presentation img{

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
#anledning{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 350px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  clear: both;

}
#utmaningar{
  background-color: white;
  width: 850px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}
#utmaningar > h4{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
footer{
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Its the id with #presentation and #anledning which are moving.

Comment: Elements with `display: inline-block;` will align to the baseline (`vertical-align: baseline;` is the default), which is causing this to render that way.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer:
Apparently if you add

vertical-align:top;

It sorts out.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vertical-align: top`

**CSS**

```
#presentation {
    width: 350px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 75px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    clear: both;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```